# Clipping raster by feature using GDAL in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, masking

I have successfully selected the feature from a shapefile (boundary) and intend to use this as a mask to clip the raster map underneath. However, having followed instructions when I open the `GDAL > Raster extraction > Clip raster by mask layer` I don't have an output layer and only an input. I have tried several options but without success.

Error code is:

QGIS version: 3.8.0-Zanzibar
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'INPUT' : '/Users/MartynMac/My Documents/GIS Projects/Tithe & Enclosure Maps/OS Georef/Ludham Catfield Crop_modified.tif', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition('parish_region_6a39b3b8_cbb3_4593_b1de_4f956d31c796', True), 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : None, 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }
 
GDAL command:
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline /var/folders/cf/_4glv9gn5171yhgxywymh9ww0000gn/T/processing_4c8576f1d012446297b0c24783abf44b/8e3fc98821ff46718579079472e8e09c/MASK.shp -crop_to_cutline "/Users/MartynMac/My Documents/GIS Projects/Tithe & Enclosure Maps/OS Georef/Ludham Catfield Crop_modified.tif" /var/folders/cf/_4glv9gn5171yhgxywymh9ww0000gn/T/processing_4c8576f1d012446297b0c24783abf44b/42b858586ae74639b5c42371a2a19e25/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: gdalwarp: command not found 
Execution completed in 0.19 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/var/folders/cf/_4glv9gn5171yhgxywymh9ww0000gn/T/processing_4c8576f1d012446297b0c24783abf44b/42b858586ae74639b5c42371a2a19e25/OUTPUT.tif'}
 
Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.

- /var/folders/cf/_4glv9gn5171yhgxywymh9ww0000gn/T/processing_4c8576f1d012446297b0c24783abf44b/42b858586ae74639b5c42371a2a19e25/OUTPUT.tif

You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: In your screenshot the Input Layer is blank, did you set this to the raster layer when you tried it? Also I'm confused as to why you can't check 'Selected Features Only' for the Mask Layer?

Comment: In the input I selected the Parish boundaries and yes i used selected feature only. The screen shot was to show lack of output layer. The tutorial I was following had that so I assumed I was doing something wrong. Sorry for confusion. All I want to do is crop/clip the raster layer map with the Shapefile boundary. Thanks

Comment: If you scroll down the output layer option is called 'Clipped (mask)'.

Comment: Doh. Never realised that was further down. But I now have a further problem. I thought the input layer was the shapefile but when I try select I only have the raster files as potential inputs and then after run get error “files are not supported as outputs for this algorithm” Help again if possible. Thanks

Comment: The input layer is the layer that you want to clip, so it's the raster layer. The mask layer is the layer that you are using the clip the input layer, so it would be the shapefile.

Are you getting that error when you do what I just said?

Comment: Yes. I am setting the input as my raster geofer map and the Parish boundary shapefile as the mask layer and selecting features only. I have also named clipped output at bottom.

Comment: The output should either be left as '[Save to temporary file]' (in which case it will create a temporary scratch layer as the output which you can then save somewhere permanent) or else it should include the full directory path, so if you want to call the output 'raster clip output' then it should be something like 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\raster clip output.tif'. Click the dotted symbol on the right hand side to choose where to save it and what to call it.

Comment: I left as save temporary and still doesn’t work as says following layer not correctly generated

Comment: Can you edit your question with what you've tried so far and include a screenshot of the error you're getting?

Comment: I don’t seem be able to upload screenshots in comments so assume I will need do via questions unless there is direct way of commenting with you?

Comment: You can edit your original question and add an update with what you've tried and some screenshots.

Comment: I’ve uploaded as new question and put your tag in header. Hope ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96102/discussion-between-gideonsway-and-teddytedted).